# Get data from a collection with firestore ionic 4

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, ionic4

I would like to get unique data from doc from a collection with firebase firestore

So i use to get all data:

```
 ngOnInit() {

return this.firestore.collection('users').snapshotChanges()



.subscribe(data => {


  console.log(data);
  this.utilisateurs = data;
  console.log(this.passided);

});


}
```

and this to get unique id :

```
this.passided = this.navParams.get('id');
```

And i tried to do this :

return `this.firestore.collection('users').doc(this.passided).snapshotChanges()`

[image: firestore]

but don't work, can you help me please?

Comment: add the code where you are using `this.firestore.collection('users').doc(this.passided).snapshotChanges()` and add a screenshot of your firestore that is in the firebase console

Comment: added the picture

Comment: arer you getting the id value `console.log(this.passided);`?

Comment: Yes of course  "tAB12BdparcelpbXEWRm"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`snapshotChanges()` is a method inside class `AngularFirestoreCollection` which returns an Observable of data as a `DocumentChangeAction`.

If you want to manipulate documents, then you can use the following methods:

`set(data: T)` - Destructively updates a document's data.

`update(data: T)` - Non-destructively updates a document's data.

`delete()` - Deletes an entire document. Does not delete any nested collections.

---

Therefore, this `this.firestore.collection('users').doc(this.passided).snapshotChanges()` wont work since `snapshotChanges()` is not a method in the `document.ts`

For reference:
https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/firestore/documents.md#snapshotchanges

https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/src/firestore/collection/collection.ts#L97

Comment: the last console.log(data) give this : {payload: DocumentSnapshot, type: "value"}
payload: DocumentSnapshot {_firestore: Firestore, _key: DocumentKey, _document: Document, _fromCache: true, _hasPendingWrites: false}
type: "value"
__proto__: Object

Comment: try `this.firestore.collection('users').doc(this.passided).valueChanges().subscribe(data => { console.log(data); });`

Comment: this.firestore.collection('users').doc(this.passided).valueChanges().subscribe(data =>
{ 
  console.log(data);

 }); I added it and in console it give me the good line in my database with all the datas of doc, but how to put it in html? this.utilisateurs = data; ? Thanks

Comment: Use string interpolation for example `<h3>Current customer: {{ currentCustomer }}</h3>`

Comment: Or add it to the object `this.utilisateurs` by doing `this.docData = data; this.utilisateurs["documentData"] = this.docData;`

Comment: Did you understand how?

Comment: Do like this `this.utilisateurs by doing this.docData = data; this.utilisateurs["documentData"] = this.docData;` then do `console.log(this.utilisateurs)` to see the data and then in the html you can `<p>{{utilisateurs.documentData.nom}}</p>`